# Problems with DSolve with initial condition

Tags: differential-equations

In *Mathematica* v. 13.1 (Mac OS), why does

```
DSolve[{m y''[t] == -k y[t], y[0] == y0, y'[1] == v0},
  y[t], t]
```

give a solution, but

```
DSolve[{m y''[t] == -k y[t], y[0] == y0, y'[0] == v0},
  y[t], t]
```

not?

This is just Newton's equation under a Hook's Law force, which should give a harmonic solution.  The initial condition concerning the speed, y'[ ], works with positive time, but not zero.

[image]

Comment: I do not currently have `13.1` only `13.2` and it works; see the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65FKy.png). I am inclined to say that this could be a bug(?) and wait for others to verify. I am pretty sure you know the work-around, so I don't bother writing it down :)

Comment: Both v11.3, v13.1 and v13.2 work.

Comment: Both work with `"13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)"` and `"13.2.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (November 18, 2022)"`

Comment: also both work for me on 13.2 on windows 10. screen shot ![Mathematica graphics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UvUq.png)

Comment: v12.2 on Win7-x64 shows this [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnAv4.png).

Comment: From the new screen shot you have, it looks like you had earlier definition. Try `ClearAll[Derivative]` or just `Clear[Derivative]` or from clean kernel and see if this fixes it.

Comment: @Nasser:  That was it.  Thanks so much.  I cleared all the *variables*, but not `Derivative`.

Comment: great, glad it worked. I got a hint when I saw `True` show up in your screen shot.